# prunePlan() takes occasionally over 40 seconds!

Tags: navigation, navfn, ros-fuerte, global-planner, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am wondering how it is possible that prunePlan takes occasionally over 40 seconds?
I can't find anything in there that causes this long computation.

It's hard to debug because it doesn't occur that often but we managed at least to localize it to this function:

```
void prunePlan(const tf::Stamped<tf::Pose>& global_pose, std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan, std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& global_plan){
ROS_ASSERT(global_plan.size() >= plan.size());
std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>::iterator it = plan.begin();
std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>::iterator global_it = global_plan.begin();
double global_pose_x = global_pose.getOrigin().x();
double global_pose_y = global_pose.getOrigin().y();
while(it != plan.end()){
    const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& w = *it;
    // Fixed error bound of 2 meters for now. Can reduce to a portion of the map size or based on the resolution
    double x_diff = global_pose_x - w.pose.position.x;
    double y_diff = global_pose_y - w.pose.position.y;
    double distance_sq = x_diff * x_diff + y_diff * y_diff;
    if(distance_sq < 1){
        ROS_DEBUG("Nearest waypoint to <%f, %f> is <%f, %f>\n", global_pose.getOrigin().x(), global_pose.getOrigin().y(), w.pose.position.x, w.pose.position.y);
        break;
    }
    it = plan.erase(it);
    global_it = global_plan.erase(global_it);
}
}
```

Has anyone an idea what I could do here?

**Edit:**

We also found out that the length of the global plan coming in, has sometimes some "outliers".
For example the planner outputs 800, 750, 600, **15000**, 400,... (We compute the path more than once during approaching a goal)

And at this peak the delay is happening.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/121791/pruneplan()-takes-occasionally-over-40-seconds!/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2014-01-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you often erase single elements (which you do) from your container I'd suggest to use std::list rather than std::vector. If you erase from std::vector elements other than the end, the entire underlying storage needs to be reallocted, which might take long if its a huge vector...

See ref of std::vector [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/]:

> Because vectors use an array as their
> underlying storage, erasing elements
> in positions other than the vector end
> causes the container to relocate all
> the elements after the segment erased
> to their new positions. This is
> generally an inefficient operation
> compared to the one performed for the
> same operation by other kinds of
> sequence containers (such as list or
> forward_list).

Note: If you can not change your function signature you could copy to std::list and back before iterating:

```
// copy to std::list
std::list<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped> my_local_plan( plan.begin(), plan.end() );

// do you iteration stuff here with list 
//.....

// copy back to arg 

plan.clear();
plan = std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>( my_local_plan.begin(),my_local_plan.end() );
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2014-01-23**:
Thanks for the info! Looks promising! We try this, but also the vector erase version where you can give start and end point to erase from. Maybe that's also faster.